# how to block free text entering in angular ui-select

Tags: angularjs, ui-select, angular-ui-select

Lib link : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

Is there any way to Block the user edit in  multiSelect ?

**I want to allow user to only clear the previously selected data ,
But how to block him from entering any free text in the ui-select**

http://plnkr.co/edit/juqoNOt1z1Gb349XabQ2?p=preview

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="multipleDemo.colors" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="color in availableColors | filter:$select.search">
      {{color}}
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

Referring above code and plunker ,
         Currently in the ui-select "Blue , Red " color's are selected and user can clear those values, but if user tries to enter some text in the ui select its allowing for modification ,

"but my requirement is to block the user from entering such texts in that field."

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

**Prevent to enter letter in select box** 
you can use **onkeypress** attribute

live code here http://plnkr.co/edit/jE0qBpewzvHG5oamB7vQ?s=TIKKc2Zmyq5lcvXI&p=preview

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="multipleDemo.colors" onkeypress="return false;" theme="select2" ng-change="call()" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
<ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices repeat="color in availableColors | filter:$select.search">
  {{color}}
</ui-select-choices>
```

Selected: {{multipleDemo.colors}}

---

Comment: sorry . please remove "call() " on ng-change i just post it for verification. forgot remove it.

Answer (score 1):

`ui-select-match` is used to display the selected value that can also contain a template.

I'd suggest you to maintain two templates to shown inside the `ui-select-match` element. 1st one will be shown when ui-select is not disable and the other one would be when `ui-select` is disable.

**Markup**

```
  <ui-select multiple ng-model="multipleDemo.colors" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">
      <span ng-if="!disabled">{{$item}}</span>
      <span ng-if="disabled">
        <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="$select.removeChoice($index)" tabindex="-1"></a>
        {{$item}}
      </span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="color in availableColors | filter:$select.search">
      {{color}}
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/faeH3M8gCCdhykUSgIxP?p=preview&s=TIKKc2Zmyq5lcvXI)

I don't think so the there is any solution on this by `ui-select`. Above is workaround by me :-)

Hopefully this would help you, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the search input text exists is a real trouble when we use pads and smartphones. The keyboard always pops up.

```
<ui-select 
       multiple ng-model="multipleDemo.colors" 
       onkeypress="return false;" 
       theme="select2" 
       ng-change="call()" 
       ng-disabled="disabled" 
       style="width: 300px;"
       class="disable-filter"
       >
```

I try to add all of this but it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to P.JAYASRI answer, you can also add this SASS CSS to remove the input cursor:

```css
.ui-select-container.disable-filter {
    .ui-select-search {
        color: transparent;
        text-shadow: 0 0 0 gray;
    }
}
```

So it would look like:

```html
<ui-select 
           multiple ng-model="multipleDemo.colors" 
           onkeypress="return false;" 
           theme="select2" 
           ng-change="call()" 
           ng-disabled="disabled" 
           style="width: 300px;"
           class="disable-filter"
           >
  ...
```